# Regular expression, "just group, don't capture", doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, regex

```
x = "abcdefg"
x = x.match(/ab(?:cd)ef/)
```

shouldn't x be abef? it is not, it is actually abcdef

Why is it that my ?: not having any effect? (of course my understanding could very well be wrong)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`(?:...)` still *matches*, it just doesn't create a new group for purposes of `\1`/`$1`/`.groups(1)`/etc.

Comment: So to achieve what I want, I'd have to do a = x.match(/(ab)(?:cd)(ef)/); x = a[1] + a[2]; correct?

Comment: @wizard: You could do that, yes, but the none-capturing group isn't necessary for that particular expression. `/(ab)cd(ef)/` would do the same job. `x.replace(/(ab)cd(ef)/, "$1$2");` would do it even better, but I imagine your real expression is a little more complicated than your example here :-).

Answer (score 5):

Your understanding is wrong.  The group will still be part of the main capture, but it won't count as a sub-expression capture.  The following would return an array of two matches:

```
x = "abcdefg"
x = x.match(/ab(cd)ef/)
```

Array index 0 would be "abcdef" (the complete match) and array index 1 would be "cd", the sub-expression capture.  Adding the `?:` tells the regex not to care about capturing the sub-expression, the full match is still fully captured.

From your other comments, there are a number of ways you could do what you're trying to do.  For instance:

```
x.replace(/(ab)cd(ef)/, "$1$2");
x.slice(0, x.indexOf("cd")) + x.slice(x.indexOf("cd") + 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other replies, if you really need to match only the outside expressions in regex, you would have to do something like this:

```
x = "abcdefg"
xarr = x.match(/(ab)(?:cd)(ef)/)
x = xarr[1] + xarr[2]
```

But really regex isn't meant for this case.

Comment: Thanks and agree with you, btw, I think you meant + instead of &

Comment: Ah, yes, my bad. Too much VB.Net.